# Cross compilation issue using CodeSourcery and Pandaboard

Tags: embedded-linux, codesourcery, pandaboard

I am new to Pandaboard development. I am using CodeSourcery cross compiler to cross compile my application code. My application is a simple 'hello world' app. I am using this for cross-compilation:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  app.c -o app.out -march=armv5
```

I am able to generate the `app.out`.
But when I copied this app.out to my panda board and tried to execute it, I got this exception:

```
-bash: ./app.out: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you please check if executable attribute is set for app.out on the board? "ls -la"

Comment: ya executable attribute is set for app.out.

Comment: Why are you using `armv5` for an `armv7-a` device?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved using the static linking of shared libraries.The command to do the same is given below.

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  app.c -o app.out -march=armv5 -static

Comment: It means that when you are doing dynamic linking, your toolchain dynamic linker is different from the one on your target rootfs. You can check dynamic linker by using readelf -x .interp YOUR_EXECTUABLE